# If determinism is true, what was the first event? Is time infinite?

Tags: ethics

How can all events be causally related if there is no initial event?

Answer (score 0):

Determinism handles the first event very carefully.  From [SEP's article on causal determinism](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/determinism-causal/):

> Determinism: The world is governed by (or is under the sway of) determinism if and only if, given a specified way things are at a time t, the way things go thereafter is fixed as a matter of natural law.

That definition is written in a form which focuses on the future state of the world given a present state, sidestepping the touchy issue of first events or uncaused events.

Obviously not everyone agrees to the same definition, but this is one reliable approach with substantial acceptance.